# Magento 1.9 checkout/onepage after login redirect to checkout/onepage

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, login, redirect

Am using **Magento 1.9**. When customer login in `checkout/onepage` page, it redirect to `customer/account`.

I want to remove this flow.

If customer login in `checkout/onepage` page redirect to same page I mean `checkout/onepage` page.

I tried this but no use

> admin > System > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration >
>   Loggin Option

then make **Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in** make it **NO**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rewrite in local :

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php,
```

the `loginPostAction()` then replace

```
$this->_loginPostRedirect();
```

with

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

Comment: Yes ;) good luck